# Targets not configured for logger. Linux + MONO

Tags: nlog

I'm using NLOG with Linux + MONO ASP.NET WebService and I'm not able to log two different file.
ASMX file have two different methos and I would like to log in separate logging file

This is Nlog.config

```
...
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="sendMail"  xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}_sendMail_${level}.log"
            layout="${time} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />  

    <target name="checkMail"  xsi:type="File" fileName="${logDirectory}/${shortdate}_checkMail_${level}.log"
            layout="${time} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />   
</targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="sendMail" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="sendMail" />
    <logger name="checkMail" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="checkMail" />   
 </rules> 
</nlog>
```

This is the log file:

```
2020-04-20 01:42:39.6781 Debug LogFactory Flush with timeout=15 secs
2020-04-20 01:42:39.6907 Debug FileTarget(Name=sendMail_wrapped): Process file '/var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_sendMail_Info.log' on startup
2020-04-20 01:42:39.6907 Debug FileTarget(Name=checkMail_wrapped): Process file '/var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_checkMail_Info.log' on startup
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7058 Debug Creating file appender: /var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_checkMail_Info.log
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7058 Debug Creating file appender: /var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_sendMail_Info.log
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7442 Debug Flush completed
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7442 Info Shutdown() called. Logger closing...
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7442 Info Closing old configuration.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7442 Debug LogFactory Flush with timeout=15 secs
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7442 Debug Flush completed
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7442 Debug Closing logging configuration...
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7490 Debug Closing target 'AsyncWrapper Target[sendMail](File Target[sendMail_wrapped])'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7533 Debug Closed target 'AsyncWrapper Target[sendMail](File Target[sendMail_wrapped])'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7533 Debug Closing target 'File Target[sendMail_wrapped]'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7585 Debug FileAppender Closing Invalidate - /var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_sendMail_Info.log
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7620 Debug Closed target 'File Target[sendMail_wrapped]'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7620 Debug Closing target 'AsyncWrapper Target[checkMail](File Target[checkMail_wrapped])'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7620 Debug Closed target 'AsyncWrapper Target[checkMail](File Target[checkMail_wrapped])'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7639 Debug Closing target 'File Target[checkMail_wrapped]'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7639 Debug FileAppender Closing Invalidate - /var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_checkMail_Info.log
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7639 Debug Closed target 'File Target[checkMail_wrapped]'.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7639 Debug Finished closing logging configuration.
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7639 Debug Stopping file watching for path '/var/www/wsMail' filter 'NLog.config'
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7775 Debug Targets not configured for logger: sendMail
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7775 Debug Targets not configured for logger: checkMail
2020-04-20 01:42:39.7775 Info Logger has been closed down.
```

This is the code in VS2019

```
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)>
<ToolboxItem(False)>
Public Class wsMail
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
    Public Credentials As AuthHeader
    Public smLog As NLog.Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("sendMail")
    Public cmLog As NLog.Logger = LogManager.GetLogger("checkMail")
    Public messageID As String = Nothing
    Public retMsg As String = Nothing
    Public retRemoteMsg As String = Nothing
......
    cmLog.Error("|" & idCustomer & "|" & remoteIP & "|wrong Password|")
    smLog.Debug("- v1.0.1 |" & idCustomer & "|" & remoteIP & "|" & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace & "|")
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot

Comment: The NLog Logger used for logging is called like this `LogManager.GetLogger("sendMail").Info("Send")`  and `LogManager.GetLogger("checkMail").Info("Check")` ? The actual Logger-Name must match the name used in `<rules><logger>`-section. Can you show how you create the Logger and call it?

Comment: Hello, I added in the post how I implemented Nlog

Comment: The logging-statements seems valid. And the InternalLogger actually shows that it is writing to the files `/var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_checkMail_Info.log` and `/var/log/wsMail/2020-04-20_sendMail_Info.log` are these files empty, or do they exists ?

Comment: They don't exists

Comment: Very strange that NLog is not complaining about writing. Have you checked file-permissions? Anyway no more ideas, not expert on Mono and Linux.

Comment: the permissions are OK, otherwise it would not even write the log file.
However, this problem arose when I decided to divide the logs by type of methods within the web service

Comment: another more info: restarted apache, the wrtiting now works but the logs writes the the same things

Comment: MORE INFO
The same problem in WINDOWS with the difference that it write both logs with the same content.

Comment: Sounds like you have a new problem, and the solution to your previous problem was to restart Apache. Maybe start documenting the new problem then. Remember users at StackOverflow cannot see what is going on your screen. Can you give an example of issue "logs writes the same things" maybe show how you call logger, and what output you see in the files? Have you made changes to your logging-code or NLog.config since you started you question? Maybe update question to reflect latest changes/discoveries